# Writing to a local file in Qt6 Windows

Tags: windows, qt, file, qt6

I have a Qt6 app (Windows only) that store settings data as some .json files.
Like

```
app/
  app.exe
  settings/
    a.json
    b.json
```

When I read the file, everything is ok.
But when I'm opening an app not as admin and trying to update .json via write, nothing happens.

```cpp
QFile file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings/a.json");
if (file.open(QIODeviceBase::WriteOnly) == false) {
    return; // <- here is the fail
}
QJsonArray json;
for (const auto& config: _configs) {
    json.push_back(ToJson(config));
}
file.write(QJsonDocument{json}.toJson());
```

How it can be solved without requiring an admin rights?
Maybe Qt can offer some other mechanizm...?

Comment: Did you check the error code? What the `file.error()` returns? The list of error codes is here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledevice.html#FileError-enum

Answer (score 0):

May be what you can try is, changing permissions to the file before trying to open it as a write mode.

There are few variants of `QFile::setPermissions` (Below code hand typed. Not tested.)

```
QFile file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings/a.json");

//Set permission
file.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser);

//or

QFile::setPermissions(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings/a.json", QFileDevice::WriteUser);
```